# Calling Field Names from a List of Strings

Tags: java, string, list, field

I have a class as such:

```
public interface ControlService extends RemoteJsonService
{

    public void myValues( String [] Names, AsyncCallback<Map<String,RegisterValues>> callback); 

    public class RegisterValues
    {
        int FirstField;
        int SecondField;
                //etc. 200 times
```

I have a string as such:

```
String[] fieldValues = new String[]{"FirstField", "SecondField", ....}; //200 of these
```

My attempt at calling upon these fields (the important part is towards the end):

```
public class RegistersPanel implements TestStandPanel, ChangeHandler
{
    private ControlService service_;

    public RegistersPanel(){

        service_.RegisterValues( Names, new AsyncCallback<Map<String,ControlService.RegisterValues>>()
                {
                public void onSuccess( Map<String,ControlService.RegisterValues> result )
                    {

                        for( String Name : result.keySet() ){
                            for (String Values : fieldValues){
                                message+=result.get(Name).getField(Values); //something like this but I can't quite figure out the syntaxt
                                //message+=result.get(Name).FirstField; this is tedious 
                            }
```

As you can see, I can't just use `getField`, and Eclipse is giving me no helpful options - any advice?

Comment: 200 of these? Are you serious. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Use GSON to parse a Map of Maps - you can't do it without doing this silly/ugly method. I just want to call upon these field values without having to type it out another 200 times.

Comment: And the number is actually closer to 256 values

Comment: Fiz, are you sure you can't do it using another method?

Comment: I've asked and no one seems to be able to give me a pointer to a better way to parse a Map of Maps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637077/parsing-json-map-of-maps-with-gson

Comment: @fiz Take a look at your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637077/parsing-json-map-of-maps-with-gson . Maybe you can now solve part of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something what you are looking for inside the double for loop,

```
RegisterValues  regValue=reuslt.get(Name);      
regValue.getClass().getDeclaredField(Values).getInt(regValue);
```

This is not the exact solution. This just gets you access to the fields value inside that class. 
P.S: that `Values` would look nice if changed to `value`

Comment: Hmmm almost but not quite

Comment: `The method getDeclaredField(String) is undefined for the type Class<capture#1-of ? extends ControlService.RegisterValues>`

Comment: try this exactly : `result.get(Name).getClass().getDeclaredField(Values).getInt(regValue);`